# How can I aggregate a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
user event score
1      2     0.5
1      3     0.2
2      3     0.7
3      1     0.9
3      4     0.1
```

and I want to get the result:

```
user event
1    2,3
2    3
3    1,4
```

How can I do this in R? 
Sometimes, I think R's lacking of base data structures in programming languages such as Java or Python makes my work inconvinient.

Comment: Which Python data structure are you trying to emulate here? A dictionary with user IDs as keys and list of event scores as values?

Comment: Yes, I just want to build a map as your description. @Marius

Comment: Sometimes I think people's lack of understanding of R data structures makes our efforts at education inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `mydata`, do:

```
aggregate(event ~ user, mydata, I)
```

to get a list that retains the numeric representation or

```
aggregate(event ~ user, mydata, paste, collapse = ", ")
```

Which pastes the values to create a character vector.

Here's a demonstration of how these are stored differently:

```
x1 <- aggregate(event ~ user, mydata, paste, collapse =",")
x2 <- aggregate(event ~ user, mydata, I)
x1$event
# [1] "2,3" "3"   "1,4"
x2$event
# $`0`
# [1] 2 3
# 
# $`1`
# [1] 3
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 4
#
```

I personally prefer using `I` to `paste` so that I can use `lapply()` on that column if I need to later.

Comment: How can I pass the argument sep=" " to the paste function?

Comment: @jerry_sjtu, why would you want/need to? Here, I've used the `collapse` argument because you're just trying to "collapse" all the elements from a single vector. The `sep` argument is more for when you are pasting together multiple vectors. As an example, try this: `x <- 1:3; y <- 4:6; paste(x, sep = ", "); paste(x, collapse = ", "); paste(x, y, sep = ", "); paste(x, y, collapse = ", ")`. Since you mentioned `sep = " "`, just replace `collapse = ", "` with `sep = " "` or just put `paste` by itself with no arguments. FYI: This will coerce the numbers in the event column to characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
 data.frame(user=unique(dat$user), event=tapply(dat$event, dat$user, c)  )
#
  user event
1    1  2, 3
2    2     3
3    3  1, 4
```

Comment: This statement works becuase the event column is ordered by factor dat$user and there is no mapping relation? It is interesting since I always try to map.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "no mapping relation". It is true that it works because the rows can be cross classified and the `unique` function will preserve the ordering that is used by `tapply`.